# Why does my character slide off of the platform if I'm using MovePosition, but not if I'm setting transform.position

Tags: unity, rigidbody, moving-platforms

I have a platform which consists of a box collider, a rigidbody2d and a script which moves the platform through waypoints.

I also have a Rigidbody2d character which can move around and jump.

One of the most common solutions I've found for having the character stay on a moving platform is by parenting it to the platform while the player is on it and removing the platform parent when the player jumps/walks off.

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag(Tags.Player))
        {
            other.transform.SetParent(platform);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag(Tags.Player))
        {
            other.transform.SetParent(null);
        }
    }
```

I have noticed that this method works only if the platform is moved by setting the `transform.position` directly and if I use `Rigidbody2D.MovePosition` my character still slides off.

Why is that, and what would be proper way of having my character stay on the platform if the platform is moved by `MovePosition`?

Comment: Rigidbody physics are independent of parenting, so parenting does not create a relationship between the body and the moving platform. You should factor the platform's travel into your MovePosition or velocity calculations.

Comment: I see. In that case, though, my player will have velocity when he is standing still on a moving platform which doesn't make sense to me. Like if I'm using velocity as a parameter for walking animation then my character will be walking on the platform even if they appear still. Is there any way I can move the player along the platform without affecting it's velocity?

Comment: Hint: when you're sitting "still" in a moving car, you have a velocity. Your error is setting the animation off of the absolute world velocity, rather than using velocity relative to the surface you're standing on.

Comment: I see. Makes sense. So in that regard, the player entity should be aware that it is on a moving entity, and it's relative velocity would then be the body velocity - platform velocity? If you want you can compose an answer out of your comments so that I can accept it, or I'll try and compose an answer myself when I get around to implementing it.